# Can't flip text on a path in Photoshop Elements 10

Tags: photoshop-elements

I've added text on the bottom of an elliptical path in Photoshop Elements 10.  Unfortunately the text is upside down.  I found several PSE tutorials that say something like, "if you drag below the path the text will flip upside down."  I've tried it with the layer selected, the text selected, as well as with the bounding box showing.  No matter what I do, dragging either moves or rotates the whole layer instead of flipping the text.  How can I flip the text over so it follows the inside of the path?

Answer (score 0):

Had trouble with this also, you need to:

- Select the shape tool - which on mine is under "draw" the third tool down on the right.
- In the shape options you have to choose the black arrow.
- The arrow/shape thing you see on all the clips come up.

Then it flips as they show.